# Core Data versioning and migrating with custom policy

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I've found documentation very limited and my problem solution nowhere.

I need to add new entity (with relationship to existing one). Also add and rename some of attributes of existing entity.

Lightweighted example:

Old model has one entity `Item` with one attribute `name`.

In new model I want to `Item` to have one new attribute `dateAdded` and rename `name` to `title`. At this point, if `dateAdded` would be optional or given default value, I could use lightweight migration feature. Correct me if I am wrong.

But I also want to add new `List` entity with `title` attribute. And add to-many relationship. List can be empty or have many items. Item have to refer to exactly one list.

So I am confused in what everything I have to do and what order.

1. Turn on migration with lightweighted migration feature disabled (`NSDictionary* options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];`).
2. Create a new version of model. There I do changes I want to.
3. Create a new mapping model. Source is old model, target is new model. In `ItemToItem` I set `title` to `$source.name`.

Besides Xcode is still crashing on working with mapping model I do not know what to do next. I think I have to create one instance of `List` in context and make all items referring to it because of relationship policy. And I thing I should use custom `NSEntityMigrationPolicy` to do this. Any help to accomplish this challenge?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I did it...

My first 3 steps were correct. Continue scenario:

ADD4. Do an `ItemToItemMigrationPolicy`, a subclass of `NSEntityMigrationPolicy`. Override:

```
- (BOOL)beginEntityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError **)error
{
    List* list = (List*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"List" inManagedObjectContext:[manager destinationContext]];
    list.name = @"Default list";

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:(NSManagedObject *)sInstance entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError **)error
{
    Item* item = (Item*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[mapping destinationEntityName] inManagedObjectContext:[manager destinationContext]];
    item.dateAdded = [NSDate date];
    task.title = [sInstance valueForKey:@"name"];

    [manager associateSourceInstance:sInstance withDestinationInstance:item forEntityMapping:mapping];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)createRelationshipsForDestinationInstance:(NSManagedObject *)dInstance entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError **)error
{

    NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"List"];
    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name LIKE 'Default list'"];
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;

    NSError* fetchRequestError = nil;
    NSArray* listsArray = [manager.destinationContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&fetchRequestError];
    if (fetchRequestError) {
        NSLog(@"%@", fetchRequestError.localizedDescription);
    }
    List* list = [listsArray lastObject];

    ((Item*)dInstance).list = list;

    return YES;
}
```

ADD5. In Xcode in mapping model set ItemToItem migration policy to custom with `ItemToItemMigrationPolicy` value.

ADD6. Make your new model version current and generate (replace) classes from new or changed entities.

ADD7. Do changes in your code, for example `item.name` no more works. Now it is `item.title`. Clean project and run.

Comment: Why lightweight need to be disabled for heavyweight? It is working for me. So my dream code is wrong?!!

Comment: I did all the steps you have mentioned but in my case, SQLite got corrupted and methods have been called from NSEntityMigrationPolicy. I added migration DEBUG log, from the log it says migration has been completed but later it crashed while trying to fetch data since SQlite got corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding a new entity, then you will need to use a custom mapping model and turn off lightweight migration.

One important thing. When working with migration, make sure you start with a fresh example of the existing persistent store every time especially if you have had crashes. If you don't, you can corrupt the store which will cause errors to snowball.

Comment: I'm midway into my migration initiative.  AFAIK, you can avoid  store corruption issues my checking for and removing the temporary store before attempting migration.  This will also ensure your app isn't trying to migration with a corrupted store in the case where migration fails to user intervention, power loss, etc.

Comment: @stephen Hey, could you please elaborate more what are the reasons behind SQLite corruption, I am stuck here, in my case data got corrupted and not a single method called from NSEntityMigrationPolicy subclass.

[error] error: (11) Fatal error.  The database at /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8940278E-4AA7-4318-8EDA-3EB1B9B8EE1A/Documents/Lido_mPilot.sqlite is corrupted.  SQLite error code:11,

Comment: It's been 6 years since I worked with this stuff.  Here's a list of common SQLite corruption scenarios: https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html