# Core Data Migration - Table Already Exists

Tags: ios, core-data, migration

I have an existing iPad application to which I've just added core data versioning.  I've been through the documentation and followed the steps detailed.  Now after choosing my new model as the current versioned model and trying to run it on my dev device from xCode I get the following error:

> 2012-03-28 07:35:42.137 DocsOnTap[2603:707] CoreData: error: (1) I/O error for database at /var/mobile/Applications/06EECF01-3598-4513-8A3A-BE4FD49EEBF6/Documents/.DocsOnTap.sqlite.migrationdestination_41b5a6b5c6e848c462a8480cd24caef3.  SQLite error code:1, 'table Z_2TAG already exists'

The only change that I made to my model was to add in a single new entity.  I have a table named Tag in my model - that appears to be what the error is referring to.

If I revert my current versioned model back to the previous model version then I can run my app on my dev device from Xcode without error.

I have read that there can be problems trying to use core data migration on dev devices.  However I just want to test the process to be sure that when we update our app in the Appstore the migration works as expected for our customers.

Comment: You need to install your original app with the original model each time you want to test migration. As you make breaking changes to the new version in dev you have to delete and reinstall the app (unless you version dev changes).

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you.  I have my original app with original model on my dev device.  I changed my existing app to add core data versioning, added a new model, made it the current model, added an entity to the new model.  Then I tried to run on the dev device and got the error above.  What do you mean by "version dev changes"?

Comment: I was saying that if you version the datamodel (version 2.0 for example), and then you add a table. The first time you run the code on top of the version 1 data model it will auto migrate as long as you've added the code. Now if you stop your code and make more changes to the 2.0 data model it will not auto migrate because you just modified the same model and will likely need to remove and re run your application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well this was an obscure error.  The entity that I was adding was named AppKeys - this must be the name of an entity used internally by core data or SQL Lite.  I went back to scratch and found that I could add and migrate other attributes and entities without any problems.  However if I tried once again to add my entity named AppKeys then I got the same error saying that 'table Z_2TAG already exists'.  So the resolution to my problem is to choose another entity name.  It is a pity that this is not documented somewhere obvious - or that the error was not more helpful. Anyway hopefully this might just help someone else one day.

Comment: I got the same error, SQLite error code:1, SQLite error code:1, 'table ZMEASUREMENT already exists', and renaming the table fixed it for one revision.  The next time I tried migrating, I got the same error again for the new name, 'table ZMEASUREMENT2 already exists'.

Comment: thanks @daveywc. its pathetic how wonderful things make you wonder sometimes. may be NSEntityMigrationPolicy a solution for attributes and relationship (thats what I find from their definition) also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027108/core-data-versioning-and-migrating-with-custom-policy

Comment: I had a similar problem where a relationship was named `groups` and this is apparently a reserved name in iOS 7, but not 8. Renaming the relationship to something else solved the issue.

Answer (score 18):

In my case the same error appeared due to **Renaming ID** which was set in the Data Model inspector for the **Entity**. After I removed the **Renaming ID** the problem'd gone.

Comment: I did the same thing, while inserting the renaming Id I by mistake set the renaming Id for entity instead of attribute.

Comment: @VickyDhas Thx! I also did the same mistake! I overlooked my git diff 5 times until I read your comment! *facepalm*

Comment: Same issue, thanks! Had a few attributes that are renamed. Per accident also the Entity.

Comment: Aaaah! this was it. You sir saved me today :)

Comment: I think this is a side effect of how weird the Data Model editor works. You think you just selected an attribute, while the editor has moved the focus to an entity.