# Coredata migration crashes

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, core-data-migration

I have an **iOS app** written in **Swift**. The live version is 1.4.3 and it has version 2 of ".xcdatamodeld" as default.

Now I created its new version 1.5.0 which has 3rd version of ".xcdatamodeld" as default.

In Appdelegate:

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MSN_App")
        
        let fileName="MSN_App"+".sql"
        
        if let url=FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last?.appendingPathComponent(fileName){
            let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: url)
            description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
            description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions=[description]
            Log.b("COREDATA: Sqlite File ALREADY present.")
        }else{
            Log.b("COREDATA: Sqlite File NOT present yet.")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
```

Its crashing when user updates from 1.4.3 to 1.5.0.
Crash report:

> MSN_App_Release/AppDelegate.swift:518: Fatal error: Unresolved error
> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134110 "An error occurred during
> persistent store migration."
> UserInfo={sourceURL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/65182A1B-A541-485A-A5A7-BD79AFCCEB06/Library/Application%20Support/MSN_App.sql,
> reason=Cannot migrate store in-place: I/O error for database at
> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/65182A1B-A541-485A-A5A7-BD79AFCCEB06/Library/Application
> Support/MSN_App.sql. SQLite error code:1, 'table ZEKYCINFO already
> exists',
> destinationURL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/65182A1B-A541-485A-A5A7-BD79AFCCEB06/Library/Application%20Support/MSN_App.sql,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x28174e910 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
> Code=134110 "An error occurred during persistent store migration."
> UserInfo={NSSQLiteErrorDomain=1,
> NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/65182A1B-A541-485A-A5A7-BD79AFCCEB06/Library/Application
> Support/MSN_App.sql, NSUnderlyingExcep

Comment: You need to describe the differences between these model versions. It's a critical detail for why migration would succeed, or fail.

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897452/core-data-migration-table-already-exists