# core data migration - how to fill just one new object?

Tags: ios, core-data, migration

I have an app on the market which has just one object instance `a1` of class A in core data.

In the new version I now need 2 instances `b1, b2` of a new class B,and 2 instances `c1, c2` of new class `C`. here `b1` and `c1` get most data from  old `a1` while `b2` and `c2` have to be created but left empty - so do not get data from the old core data object.

All tutorials and descriptions elaborate on data transformation old -> new, but in my case its about this migration from old data to new including creating the new empty objects.

**What would be the correct way to do this, since "typical migration" does not really cover this case?**

I did the same in Android with my database, there it is really easy but I am not sure how to "press" my problem into core data migration scheme.

many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a custom migration policy. Use this post as a guideline to get started and get a good starting point for researching the docs.

[Core Data versioning and migrating with custom policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027108/core-data-versioning-and-migrating-with-custom-policy)

Comment: actually all I had to do is to di the lightweight migration and at the very end in my own code check if the new objects exist - if not, just create them. Thanks for the hint!