# How to keep data ordering after Core Data migration?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode, core-data

On current project I have a set of objects stored using Core Data.
Now I need to add one more field to DataModel.

I've added it, have created new mapping model, set it as current and successfully migrated to new data model. Everything works, but.. order of my data is lost.
For some weird reason previous developers doesn't create any order attribute to Data Model and it was sorted automatically when fetching data (by id I believe..)

After migration to new Data Model using mapping model I have random ordering of my data after each migration.
And some application logic related to order of this data is broken now.

How this issue can be resolved?
It is possible to create order attribute based on old ids?
Or how I can migrate with ids?

Already spent a day with this issue and didn't find the solution.

Thanks a lot!
Alex.

Requested retrieving data code:

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Area" inManagedObjectContext:[self context]];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];

NSError *error;
return  [[[self context] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Can you post the code for how you're retrieving the data?

Comment: @jjatie sure, added it to question text

Comment: You're not providing a `NSSortDescriptor` or `NSPredicate` to  limit and sort the results. You need to do this to have the `managedObjectContext` sort results for you.

Comment: @jjatie thanks for suggestion! I have no attribute by which this data can be sorted. Before migration it was returned in order in which it was inserted and this behaviour was correct. I believe it was sorted by internal data id. After migration data is inserted in random order. Record that was first can be 3-rd after one migration or 2-nd after another migration. My goal is to keep current order by introducing some sorting attribute based on data order before migration and use it, or migrate with data order.

Comment: You were just lucky before that the results returned in the same order as insertion; there is no guarantee of this. If you need to sort by date, have a date property and create a sort descriptor for it. You can sort by any property that exists.

Comment: @jjatie unfortunately in current Data Model I have no property by which I can sort items.. :( I want to introduce one based on old ids or migrate ids. Thanks for attention anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out how to resolve this.

I've tried to create custom policy and found that data are passed to it in correct order (like it was stored in the CoreData before migration)
here is how to create custom policy: [Core Data versioning and migrating with custom policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027108/core-data-versioning-and-migrating-with-custom-policy)

After this things became simpler. I've created *sortOrder* field and increment it for each entity in the custom policy and set it to new field *sortOrder* of my entity.

Thanks everyone for help.

Here is the code:

```
- (BOOL)createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:(NSManagedObject *)sInstance entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError **)error {
MyEntity* myEntity = (MyEntity*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[mapping destinationEntityName] inManagedObjectContext:[manager destinationContext]];

myEntity.myProp1 = [sInstance valueForKey:@"myProp1"];
//a lot of properties here..
//here is the solution - set sortOrder. Is is the property of custom policy class - one instance of this class is used for each entity migration
area.sortOrder = sortOrder;
int value = [sortOrder intValue];
sortOrder = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:value + 1];

[manager associateSourceInstance:sInstance withDestinationInstance:myEntity forEntityMapping:mapping];

return YES; }
```

Then I simply sort items on my view.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is not rely on some internal ordering. Add sort descriptors to the fetch request when you get access to data.

Also to be sure that your sorted results are processed in the sequential order, use old fashioned loop `for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++)` instead of enumerators `for (id a in array)`.

Comment: Use enumerators. From the documentation: "If you are enumerating an ordered collection, the enumeration proceeds in that order. For an NSArray, this means the first pass will be for the object at index 0, the second for object at index 1, etc.".

Comment: Thanks Vladimir! I've tried your solution with old fashioned "for" loop and order of the data is still not correct. The reason why I can't sort items by some attribute - I don't have this attribute. Sure, I can add it, but I need to keep data order for previous users and trying to find out how it can be implemented.

Comment: @Willeke The key word is "ordered". I am definitely not sure that with enumerators NSArray is scanned sequentially. It is not critical when you need to process each element of array, but when order is critical I prefer to use "old" loop - do not rely on compiler.

Comment: @AlexanderStepanov You need to find a way, how to reproduce "old" order of elements. It can be implemented either with sort descriptors in requests  or with some artificial algorithm used to postprocess (reorder) data you got after request. And please note - when you add new fields during migration, additional database file is created and your final request; result is actually a result of some internal manipulation with data from old and new tables.

Comment: @ВладимирВодолазкий 1. The docmentation says the order is the order of the array. 2. The order isn't determined by the compiler. it's determined by the implementation of `NSFastEnumeration` in `NSArray`. 3. Fast enumeration is faster. 4. Apple recommends fast enumeration. 5. I know from experience: the order is ok.

Comment: @ВладимирВодолазкий thanks! in my case it is user's data without any sortable attributes